# Absolutely positioned DIV not staying in the relatively positioned DIV parent

Tags: css

I have reduced my problem to a simple example.  I have multiple `position:relative` div containers, lets say checks, one per page.  I lay out the data on the check using `position:absolute` div's.  The layout is fine on the first check but all the following check data overlays the first check.  In this example, the check numbers are all on the first box upper right.  In one of my tests it looked OK in `print preview` but not on the screen.  I have tested in both IE and Firefox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .check {
        position : relitive;
        width : 200mm;
        height: 2.5in;
        border : 1px solid Black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="Check608" class="check" >
      <div style="height: 100%; background: #ee3e64;">Check 1</div>
      <div style="position: absolute; top: 8mm; left: 175mm;">608</div>
   </div>
   <div id="Check609" class="check" >
      <div style="height: 100%; background: #44accf;">Check 2</div>
      <div style="position: absolute; top: 12mm; left: 175mm;">609</div>
   </div>
   <div id="Check610" class="check" >
      <div style="height: 100%; background: #b7d84b;">Check 3</div>
      <div style="position: absolute; top: 16mm; left: 175mm;">610</div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `position:relitive` is it spelling mistake you did?

Comment: It's `relative` not `relitive`. Is that a typo in your question alone, or in your code as well?

Comment: I spent hours looking at the code.  Don't know when I introduced the spelling error.

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelt `relitive`. It should be `relative` like this:

```
.check {
        position : relative;
        width : 200mm;
        height: 2.5in;
        border : 1px solid Black;
}
```

That works correctly as demonstrated by this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jfngyu75/

Comment: A second set of eyes can catch the simple things.  Misspell once the copy and paste.  I must have done that trying to clean up my style sheet when I removed the inline styles.  Thanks for the catch.